# How to sort images using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a slider in which images are put according to file name and I've named my images like this

```
img-1, img-2, img-3, img-4, img-5, img-6, img-7, img-8, img-9, img-10
```

but browser is sorting like this

```
img-1, img-10, img-2, img-3, img-4, img-5, img-6, img-7, img-8, img-9
```

So how can I sort my images so in my example img-10 would go at last using jquery?

Comment: Show the code where images are loaded for slider

Comment: If you can rename your images to follow a two digit scheme: img-01, img02 ... img-10, that would solve your problem.

Comment: As i think you can't sort based on string. So better approach will be keep 'img' fixed and then 'sort the digit' and append it with 'img'

Comment: sorry for late response coz of net disturb, plugin is automatically loading all images in a div but images are appearing as my second example so I wanted to sort the divs images without any click that is on ready

Comment: Can you show the code which illustrates the way you are sorting?

Comment: @C-Link use alphabets only..like `img-a, img-b, img-c..` if you still want to use numbers then you need to add some code as shown by users below. why adding code when you can just sort.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting is happening in [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). you better add a "0" prefix to the numbers if you are sure that the images are less than 99 (I mean two digits).

Something like this:

```
"img-01", "img-02", "img-03", "img-04", "img-05", "img-06", "img-07", "img-08", "img-09", "img-10"
```

**or else**

use alphabets instead of numbering system.

```
"img-a", "img-b", "img-c", "img-d", "img-e", "img-f", "img-g", "img-h", "img-i", "img-j"
```

[Further reading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127639/68702)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to sort the image names, you can write a custom sort function using pure JS:

```
sorted = imageNames.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return parseInt(a.split('-')[1], 10) - parseInt(b.split('-')[1], 10) 
});
```

That will sort based on the numeric value found after the `-` character in your file names.

Comment: Yes, it's doing a purely numeric comparison. It splits the strings, captures anything after the `-` characters, turns them into an integers (in base 10) and then compares them.

Comment: I did but seems wrong I'm doing  var imageNames = $('#banner img');
 var sorted = imageNames.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return parseInt(a.split('-')[1], 10) - parseInt(b.split('-')[1], 10) 
});
 return sorted;

Comment: You're selecting the image elements. The sort function is written to look at their names (although you could write a custom sort function). If you want to get all the image names, try `$('img').map(function (index, elem) { return $(elem).attr('src') })`

Comment: I did this but not working.... var imageNames = $('#banner img').map(function (index, elem) { return $(elem).attr('src') });
 imageNames.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return parseInt(a.split('-')[1], 10) - parseInt(b.split('-')[1], 10) 
});

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for (no sliding as noticed by neal).

```
$('img-selector').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```